# GET method not working when sending 2 words with space using IOS sdk

Tags: php, ios

here is my code and it is work fine if I Pass one english word , but it is not working if I pass more than one words contain spaces or arabic words

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/addcomm.php?nickname=%@&comm=%@&pos=%@",nick,comm.text,postid];
    NSData *data =[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    NSString *res = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

and here is my php code :

```
$n1 = $_GET['nickname'];
$c1 = $_GET['comm'];
$p1 = $_GET['pos'];

$n = urlencode($n1);
$c = urlencode($c1);
$p = urlencode($p1);

echo $n;
echo $c;
echo $p;
```

any idea please .

Comment: Can you confirm that your NSString is properly putting the values in?

Comment: @David yes, it is working if it is one english word and no spaces

Comment: You have to URL encode nick,comm.text,postid before you insert them, i.e. `space` turns into `%20`

Comment: @DanZimm ok, what about arabic language

Comment: same thing, you would need to properly URL encode it. URL's can only be ascii, heres a w3schools link http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp and then the rfc: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt

Comment: @DanZimm sorry I could not solve the arabic problem . can you help me please

Comment: check out the post below

Comment: @DanZimm Linking to http://w3fools.com is not always wise :P

Comment: thats why i also included the rfc but w3fools or w.e is an easy to read beginners thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Arabic language I had to add to my php code :

```
mysql_query("set character_set_server='utf8'");
mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
```

and change in my Xcode code  :

```
NSASCIIStringEncoding
```

to

```
NSUTF8StringEncoding
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not is PHP code, but with your Objective C code.
You should first encode your strings before passing them to PHP.

Please change string

```
    NSData *data =[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

to string:

```
    NSData *data =[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]]];
```

This should work!

Comment: yes it is work but giving me like this : hello+world how to remove the plus, also it did not work with arabic language

Comment: yes it did remove the plus sign but I am looking for solution for the arabic language please, thank you

Comment: for arabic support try to change in Objective C code  to stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding

Comment: please do you have anther idea